# Want to run a kivy app made in windows but while running in mac os showing error

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, kivy

I want to run the main app which is connected with database, my.kv, users.txt file but when I run it it's showing me erroe message.. I made this project in window but when I try to run it in mac os it's showing me error.. please help me out guys[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems your trying to access the 'users.txt' file as if it were in the current directory. Frequently, IDEs will put the working directory somewhere else that may be inconvenient for you. You can either try to play around with these settings until you get it treat the directory you expect to be the correct directory as the working directory, or you can try working with absolute paths.

For example, if your sure you app will always have this data file right next to your 'main.py' file, you could do something like the following:

```
import os

def get_users_file():
    current_python_script = os.path.abspath(__file__)
    current_script_directory = os.path.dirname(current_python_script)
    users_file = os.path.join(current_script_directory, 'users.txt')
    return users_file

with open(get_users_file(), 'r') as file_handler:

    users_file_data = file_handler.readlines()

print(users_file_data)
```

there are other, cleaner ways to do this with things like `pkg_resources`, but I typically don't bother with using things like that until I have a proper build environment for my program.

In the future, I also recommend putting the bulk of your question into text form rather than a screen shot, as it makes it more difficult to decipher what you want.